# Bizarre Django model behavior with created/updated DateTimeFields

Tags: python, django, datetime

On each of my models, I like to track created and modified times. I always add this to my model classes:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Cool. Simple right? Yup. Or you could always do this:

```
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel

class SomeModel(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
```

Now today, for the first time ever, I'm seeing strange behavior when simply running the project on my development server vs. my live server.

**NOTE:** It is worth noting that the below behavior occurs with my manual model creation_date/modified_date setup as well as if I use TimeStampedModel from django_extensions.

On my **development server** it works as expected:

**Add new model instance**

1. Auto updates the creation_date
2. Auto updates the modified_date

**Update model instance**

1. creation_date remains unmodified from its original (expected behavior)
2. Auto updates the modified_date

However, once pulled to my **live server** we get this behavior:

**Add new model instance**

1. Auto updates the creation_date
2. Auto updates the modified_date

**Update model instance**

1. creation_date gets set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 (**unexpected behavior**)
2. Auto updates the modified_date

Development Server:

- Django 1.8
- Python 2.7.9
- MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.**25**

Live Server:

- Django 1.8
- Python 2.7.9
- MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.**24**

As you can see the only difference between them is a slight revision to MySQL.  That should not be an issue, but yet, here I am...getting this odd behavior.  Any ideas?

Comment: MySQL.... That should not be an issue hahahahaha

Answer (score 0):

There is a Datetime Bug that got fixed in 5.6.25 (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-25.html#mysqld-5-6-25-bug) - try updating your live system.

Comment: Updated MySQL to 5.6.25, restarted MySQL, restarted Apache...same issue.